# ReactJS + ReactRouter: How to define string as a reference to props in Javascript?

Tags: reactjs

Places the string as a props in Javascript like so: How can I come up with it?
          green: {
            room: 7
          },
          purple: {
            root: 8
          }
        },
      },
      {
        name: Jerome
        monday: {
          black: {
            room: 5
          },
          orange: {
            root: 6
          }
        },
        tuesday: {
          yellow: {
            room: 7
          },
          purple: {
            root: 8
          }
        },
      },
    ]

Comment: You first need to figure out why `ownProps.params` is undefined.

Comment: can you post the code where you are calling mapStateToProps?

Comment: r u using this to call profile component `<Link
    to={`/StudentsBoard/Kev/monday/blue`}
    style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow', textDecoration: 'none'}}
  ></Link>` ??

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes, and once I'm on the StudentsBoard component, I'm setting up the mapStateToProps, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your filter over `state.students` is really returning something.

Your error message is saying it is undefined.

I don't know what your function does, but I can see it expects some data like that and it works:

```
const state = {students: [{name: "beto", day: { color: "red"}}]};

const props = {params: {name: 'beto', day: { color: "red" }}};

mapStateToProps(state, props);
```

but as you can see. I am not sure if is really the data structure you have. As I see your code is wants a color that is a property of day object.

Keep in mind that in this case you must use the brackets object accessor notation to properly get your data. check this code:

```
let prop = 'sun'; 

let obj = {sun: 'red' }; 

console.log(obj.prop) // returns undefined
// explanation: returns undefined because obj does not have a prop named prop

console.log(obj[prop]) // returns red
// explanation: returns red, because it first solve the value of prop variable to 'sun' and then uses sun as prop name over your object. in the end it makes obj.sun instead of obj.prop
```

Comment: Please take a look at the update with the data structure. `state.students` returns correctly, but it is saying `day` and `color` cannot be read. Is it possible that it is because they are strings?

Comment: now I see. In this case you must use the brackets object accessor notation to properly get your data. check this code bellow

`let prop = 'sun';

let obj = {sun: 'red' };

console.log(obj.prop) // returns undefined

console.log(obj[prop]) // returns red`

Comment: Sorry but could you show an example with the code I provided?

Comment: `let mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let student = state.students.filter(student => student.name == ownProps.params.name)

  let day = ownProps.params.day
  let color = ownProps.params.color

  return {
    carFiles: student[0][day][color] //Getting an error here saying day and color are - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'day'/'color' of undefined
  }
}`